# unable to add Facebook app to page

Tags: facebook

I have previously created 3 facebook iframe apps but now I am trying to create a new app and for some reason after I go to my Apps profile page and click on 'add app to my page' the app doesn't appear on my page?

I have gone through the app settings to make sure they are all correct.
I have tried different URL's (as a test)
If I go to 'edit my page' > 'apps', the app is in the list but doesn't have 'link to to this app' like the other apps do and if I click on 'edit settings, I get the message 'There are no settings for this application.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a Canvas URL in your application settings (or possibly a Page Tab URL, it's not clear what type of app you're trying to create to me). Either way, doesn't look like it's set.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean the setting that says "Deauthorize Callback:"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'Canvas URL' not 'callback URL'. I'll update my answer

Comment: You are correct! The layout of the page is different to last time I created an app and I totally over looked that section! Thanks